Vue3/Nuxt3 computed property reactivity issue with objects
I am struggling for days with this problem and I didn't find any solution even on the internet. The problem is that I have a computed property with a getter and a setter but its setter is not being called when I try to change one of its properties (value or unit).
I couldn't send the whole code that I have because it's too long so that's why I had to create a minimal snippet very similar to the one in vue's docs on Writable Computed (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed) so that I can illustrate the problem.
I created a computed property gapSize with a getter and a setter to manage an object representing size (value and unit). I expected that by mutating gapSize.value.value and gapSize.value.unit, the changes would be reactive and the view would automatically update.
However, the computed property does not seem to trigger reactivity when I modify its object's properties directly (like gapSize.value.value and gapSize.value.unit) and I also realized that the setter is not even being called.
<template>
  <div>{{ gapSize.value }}{{ gapSize.unit }}</div>
  <button @click="randomize">Randomize</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
type Size = {
  value: number | string,
  unit: string
}

const units: Array<string> = [
  'px',
  'rem',
  'em',
  '%',
  'dvh',
  'vh',
  'svh'
]

const gap = ref<Size>({
  value: 0,
  unit: 'px'
})

function randomize() {
  const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  const randomUnit = units[Math.floor(Math.random() * units.length)]
  gapSize.value.value = randomValue
  gapSize.value.unit = randomUnit
}

const gapSize = computed({
  get(): Size {
    return {
      value: Math.round(parseInt(`${gap.value.value}`)),
      unit: gap.value.unit
    }
  },
  set(newValue: Size) {
    gap.value = newValue
  }
})
</script>

I will be grateful if you guys can explain to me please why I don't see any changes when I call randomize method which is mutating the computed object properties.
And about using watchers. I have a very nested complex object in my pinia store with dozens of properties, it will be a pain to use a watcher for each of them.
Thank you.

Compare your computed set() function to how you actually call it. Notice the function expects an object param of type Size when it's called
set(newValue: Size) {
  gap.value = newValue
}

This will be called only when you make an assignment like gapSize.value = .
It can't be used for setting individual properties.
gapSize.value.value = randomValue // does NOT call gapSize.set(randomValue)
gapSize.value.unit = randomUnit // does NOT call gapSize.set(randomUnit)

Even if these statements did call the setter, you're calling it once with randomValue type (number | string) and a second time with randomUnit type (string), neither of which match the expected Size parameter type. Try rewriting your randomize function like this:
function randomize() {
  const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  const randomUnit = units[Math.floor(Math.random() * units.length)]
  gapSize.value = { value: randomValue, unit: randomUnit }
}


It makes perfect sense now, and it resolved my issue! I understand that the setter for the computed property is only triggered when assigning the entire object (gapSize.value = {...}), not when directly modifying its properties.
However, I'm wondering what would happen in a case where I have an input field using gapSize.value in its v-model. Would I need to add an @change handler to manually set the whole gapSize object to trigger the setter?
Or is there a way to make the computed property "deep-watch" changes to its object's properties and automatically call the setter?
Thank you.

I wanted to vote your answer up, but I need to have 15 reputation since this is my first question in here. Sorry! (-:
